# How to avoid pylint not-an-iterable when using a custom property class

Tags: python, pylint

My code uses the commonly used [cached_property](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/2b2d921eea7d1f896ce436ec5238890abe8b81bf/werkzeug/utils.py#L35) class from [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/). Consider the following snippet:

```python
from werkzeug import cached_property

class SampleClass(object):
    @cached_property
    def list_prop(self):
        return [1, 2]

sample = SampleClass()
for item in sample.list_prop:
    print item
```

I use pylint in my CI process. If I run the pylint [not-an-iterable](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference_guide/features.html#iterable-check-checker) check on this code, it fails even though the code is perfectly fine.

```
$ pylint --disable=all --enable=not-an-iterable prop.py
************* Module prop
E:  9,12: Non-iterable value sample.list_prop is used in an iterating context (not-an-iterable)
```

pylint works well when checking the same code with the built-in `@property` decorator instead of `@cached_property`:

```python
class SampleClass(object):
    @property
    def list_prop(self):
        return [1, 2]
```

What should I do to help pylint overcome this false positive?

Comment: If you are not using Python 3, then your classes should descend from `object`.  If you are using Python 3, then you can (probably) apply a suitable type annotation, though whether `pylint` is smart enough to understand that is a bit of an open question.  In any event, you can always use a `# pylint: disable` comment.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and inheritance from `object`. The sample here was missing it. I will edit the code snippets. @Kevin - I am not sure why you believe this inheritance should make the difference in this case.

Comment: The descriptor protocol does not work if you do not inherit from `object`.  That causes all manner of things to break down including `@property` and similar toys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are importing `cached_property` incorrectly. It lives in `werkzeug.utils`. `pylint` caught that error: `E:  1, 0: No name 'cached_property' in module 'werkzeug' (no-name-in-module)`. Here's the fixed code:

```
from werkzeug.utils import cached_property

class SampleClass(object):
    @cached_property
    def list_prop(self):
        return [1, 2]

sample = SampleClass()
for item in sample.list_prop:
    print item
```

When I run `pylint` after applying this fix, it stops complaining:

```
$ pylint test
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module test
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  3, 0: Missing class docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  5, 4: Missing method docstring (missing-docstring)
R:  3, 0: Too few public methods (1/2) (too-few-public-methods)
C:  8, 0: Invalid constant name "sample" (invalid-name)
```

Comment: The import is actually correct but it uses a [custom dynamic import mechanism](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/2b2d921eea7d1f896ce436ec5238890abe8b81bf/werkzeug/__init__.py#L115) which pylint will not infer.

Importing `cached_property` from its actual location works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem when I use the Django+ pylint :
the code is as follows:

```
queryset = A.objects.filter(col_a='a',col_b='b')
```

It will show error message:

```
Non-iterable value queryset is used in an iterating context (not-an-iterable)
```

My solution is as follows(**+all()**):

```
queryset = A.objects.filter(col_a='a',col_b='b').all()
```

It actually solved my problem, I know it seems has no much related to the issue but I google 'pylint + Non-iterable', this page will be on the top of search result, so I want to put the solution here,thanks